# Import file.bacpac in Azure blob container to Azure SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have made a web application which use azure management API, in C# (Asp.NET, not MVC). Application gets a local file DB.sql, it convert in blob file,it upload to azure container blob, all it works fine.

But now **I can't import this azure blob file to azure SQL database**,  can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Storage-SQL-Database-Tutorials/Advanced-Windows-Azure-SQL-Database-Migration-Part-3-ImportExport-Service. And you need install Microsoft.sqlServer.dac.dll . So for me this is the best way for that.

Comment: This solution depends on the execution happening on the client side. I am looking for a way to upload a bacpac to blob storage, trigger a web job that imports the blob into a new database. Is this feasible using DAC?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this PowerShell script to import bacpac files in your Blob to Azure SQL:
[Import bacpac from Azure storage](http://thecodegarden.net/import-bacpac-from-azure-storage/)

Comment: maybe you can answer this one as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66302408/how-to-know-if-bacpac-file-is-loaded-to-memory-fully-or-is-it-streamed

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to import a bacpac file, whether you're on SQL Azure or local SQL, is to use the *Import Data-Tier Application* wizard, which can be found on the context menu of the database node in SQL Server Management Studio. Follow the steps to select the bacpac file, and wizard will create a new database for you.

Comment: I know that, but it isn't useful for me, because I want press a button and web application do it all, so I need make that with code (c#).